# Safe pH levels for blood

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What exactly happens to blood cells when a persons blood is to alkaline?
I know that if your pH level goes below 6.8 or above 7.8 you will die. I have read that if you go below 6.8 your cells will stop functioning. Is the same true if you go above? If so what causes the cells to stop functioning?

Comment: I should be asked on Biology SE not here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for biology.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are a lot of different things that can go wrong if your blood's pH changes too much, in this answer I am going to focus on one of the most chemistry relevant issues with a large change in pH: the denaturing of proteins. Your body is 70% proteins by mass, and they are responsible for functions as diverse as catalyzing reactions to structural support. While many factors influence a protein's function, one of the most important aspects of a protein is its three dimensional shape. Proteins are [folded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_folding) into a shape so that they can optimally preform their function. If a protein's three dimensional structure is distorted, it will normally lose its functionality. The process of a protein losing its three dimensional structure is called denaturing, and it can be caused by a variety of factors including changes in temperature and pH. Once a protein has been denatured, the process becomes irreversible and the protein loses its functions. One of the biggest risks of a change in your blood's pH is that your proteins will start to denature, causing devastating effects on your body's function. Either an increase or a decrease in your body's pH can cause proteins to denature.